# Does DXC impose limits on conditionals and calls to TraceRay() in raytracing shader HLSL?

Tags: shader, raytracing

I have a closesthit shader in a DX12 program and the dxc.exe pass in VS2017 (15.9.7) gives me the the following error on compilation:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Raymond, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1327,5): error MSB6006: "dxc.exe" exited with code -1073741571.
1>Done building project "Raymond.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

For what it's worth (probably not a lot), the lines in the file it mentions in the error are:

```
1327    <FXC
1328        Condition                       = "'@(FxCompile)' != '' and '%(FxCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true'"
1329        Source                          = "%(FxCompile.Identity)"
1330        ToolPath                        = "$(FXCToolPath)"
```

The error seems to be most dependent on the inclusion of a call to the DX12 intrinsic function TraceRay(), which is in a wrapper function called TraceRadienceRay() :

```
#if 1
      float4 ambient = TraceRadianceRay(ambientRay, rayPayload.recursionDepth, rayPayload.sample_ID, rayPayload.medium_stack);
#else
      float4 ambient = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
#endif
```

With the #if set to 1, I get the error. Set to 0, it compiles fine. There's nothing wrong with this particular line of code. The shader used to compile, but as it has grown (it's now about 360 lines long), the error started to increase in frequency. What is really odd, is that the probability of getting the error is somewhere between 0 and 1. Sometimes it fails, but if I just compile again, it works! There appears to be a correlation between the probability of failure, and the number / level of conditional clauses in the code. I've now gone through the code and minimised these, but I can't reduce the code complexity any further without removing functionality.

I've looked up shader limitations on the web, and there do appear to be limits to things like the number of local variables and conditional clauses, but all of those limits in Shader Model 6.0 are way above what I have in my code.

I tried looking up the return value, but none of the resources I found have that return code. If you turn the value into a hex value, you get 0xFFFF_FFFF_C000_00FD but that does not match any documentation, even if you lop off all the 'F's.

There seems to be very little to go on with dxc.exe - a Google search turns up very few hits. Really hoping someone here has seen something similar and can shed some light on it.

Many thanks.

Comment: So ... it looks like the return code of C00000FD might mean "Stack Overflow". This will be a stack overflow in dxc.exe during compilation, not my shader code. I've had others with more experience writing shader code look at my shader and they can't see anything wrong with my code, so this might be a bug in dxc.exe. However - I'd still be interested to hear if anyone else has seen this, of if there are work-arounds to prevent this from happening. It's driving me up the wall.

Comment: Still have this issue. Has nobody else seen this? Still stuck.

Answer (score -1):

I signed up for S.O. just to tell you that I, too, have this issue.  I've seen it intermittently with minor code changes that seem to have no obvious syntax or usage errors.  Although I am also working on shaders and Ray Tracing, the error I am getting now is related to a function that contains a pretty vanilla switch/case statement.

I just switched from a Debug build to a Release build and it compiled.  Have you tried something similar?

Not exactly a solution, but it allowed me to get past the error.  Let me know if you have any success.